# Visual Studio 2015 Analyzer threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

After updating from **VS 2015 Update 1 RC** to **VS 2015 Update 1**, I keep getting the following error message:

> Analyzer
> 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeFixes.SimplifyTypeNames.VisualBasicSimplifyTypeNamesDiagnosticAnalyzer'
> threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' with message
> 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'

on one of my projects. **Code Analysis** is disabled on that project (as it is on all of my projects in the solution), so I tried to turn it on and off but still the same issue.

It seems that I can still build and run my solution, but things don't really seem to work properly after the upgrade:

- everything is running really slow
- after making changes and building it doesn't apply the changes

Did anyone else have this issue after the recent update or maybe even before?

Potential work-around found in here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6682 posted by user **dpoeschl**.

And this is his original text:

> **Workaround**: Check this checkbox: Tools | Options | Text Editor | Basic
> | Code Style | Qualify member access with 'Me'
>
> [image: dpoeschl's solution]
>
> This workaround has two **side-effects** (that I can think of so far):
>
> **1.** You will no longer get a visual indicator of the superfluous Me. or the associated code-fix, or the "Fix all occurrences in" options for
> easily achieving compliance.
>
> **2.** Any code generation features that generate fully qualified member accesses and depend on the Simplifier to remove them if appropriate
> (or that explicitly check this option) will now generate non-compliant
> code by default.
>
> Enabling this option is particularly non-invasive in both VS2015 &
> VS2015 Update 1 because this option is only enforced in one direction.
> That is, the checkbox being unchecked means the analyzer runs, does
> some deeper analysis (that fails in this case), and offers you a
> lightbulb when you have qualified member accesses, while the checkbox
> being checked means that we opt out of the deeper analysis very early
> and you don't get any lightbulbs telling you to add Me. qualification.

It has worked for me, it might as well fix the problem for others.

Comment: I Haven't noticed that one yet, but I have noticed plenty of other 'little' things that appear to have been broken in this update, so much so That I did a complete uninstall and reinstall in the hopes that that would cure the issue.  The jury's still out on whether or not it has.

Comment: I was having all sorts of issues with VS before the update as well so I was hoping this is going to fix some of the issues and it did fix some, but I've ended up with others :(

Comment: Believe me I feel your pain, how on earth this got through QA I'll never know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a defect introduced in Update 1 and it is already tracked [at Roslyn GitHub as #6682](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6682) since 2015-10-11.
Check there for status updates.

**Update:** [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 is now out](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) and the problem is fixed there.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll check there, hopefully they can fix it soon.

Comment: It is closed as fixed on December 23 2015.

Comment: It was reopened, then closed as fixed on Feb 3.

Comment: Found a really useful post by an user (**dpoeschl**) in your link and it seems to work for me. I've just posted it in the question. As mentioned, this is a work-around and not an actual fix for it.

Answer (score 3):

Update:

Apparently, the general issue is the code assistant is flagging calls to Shared class types when the class name is used.

For example

```
Private Shared Property Instance as Class1

Public Shared Function DefInstance1() as Class1
  ' This causes the warning
  Return Class1.Instance
End Function

Public Shared Function DefInstance2() as Class1
  ' This is okay
  Return Instance
End Function
```

For example, I assigned a value to the Synchronizing Object when inheriting from System.Timers.Timer as:

```
MyBase.SynchronizingObject = value
```

Instead of

```
SynchronizingObject = value
```

The VS Code Assistant detected this as a type name that can be simplified.

Note also, that a new warning is added each time VS starts.

Update:

It looks like another culprit is in the code generated by Visual Studio in the Application.Designer.vb:

this

```
Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices
```

is tagged for simplification to

```
ApplicationServices
```

It seems that Code Assistant has become a bit over-aggressive without QA noticing the issues at hand.

Comment: Found a culprit in a class that was inheriting from System,Timers.Timer I was setting the class SynchronizingObject:

Answer (score 0):

On March 30th, 2016, Microsoft released a new update for Visual Studio.

After installing Visual Studio Update 2 the issue seems to go away. This is the [VS Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) and [VS Update 2 Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update2-vs)

Checking the Release Notes, this is the only thing they have touched with regards to the Analyzer:

> We made Analyzer API improvements, including enabling Analyzer writers to mark their analyzers for concurrent execution, and providing control over whether analyzers run in generated code.